# Asp.net website on AWS ec2 t2 medium

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, hosting

We have an asp.net application currently running on a shared hosting provider.
The application specifications are

- **.NET 4.5** Web forms webiste.
- 1 MSSQL data base of size - **100 MB**
- Web Application size including images -  **1.2GB**
- Page visits/day - **~2500**
- Bandwidth consumed/day - **~200MB**

We are not happy with the Hosting providers and have faced a lot of issues recently. Our application requires trust level as full for some of the services and the hosting provider is unwilling to set the trust of the application as full.

Statistics obtained(1 week) from the hosting provider(See image below)

[image]

(We have around 2500 page visits a day on week days and 500 page visits on weekends)

Based on the above information, we are planning to move to AWS. I was thinking to go with a **t2 medium reserved windows instance**(It has **2 cores and 4 gb ram**) and **EBS storage**(Will cost us around 50 USD a month)

Since we have a small database when compared to enterprise standards, I was thinking to host it in the same instance. We are also planning to go with Sequel server express as this does not need licensing rights.

I have read up a lot of documentation and I am not able to reach a conclusion about the size of the instance to go for and will the t2 medium EC2 instance be able to serve my purpose?

**1. It would be great if anyone can tell me if the above t2 medium ec2 infrastructure will suit our needs?**

**2. Do I need a t2 medium instance or can I go for a lower level
    configuration ?**

Open to suggestions on change of above mentioned infrastructure as well.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of quoting page visits, etc, you are better off showing RAM and CPU utilisation.

A couple of things to consider:

1 - The t instance is a burstable throughput CPU. That means you gain 'credits' when your CPU is not being used, and when you use it (I cant remember exactly but possibly >10%?) you use up credits. This means if your average workload is either very low, or very bursty, the `t` series is a good choice, but if your workload is quite constant and high, it is a very bad choice.

2 - How static is the website? You might see benefit in decoupling the database onto an RDS instance that matches your needs, and then having the website on a spot instance to reduce cost, for example.

3 - With respect to configuration requirements, only you can answer this.

Comment: Hi henry. Since we are on a shared hosting, we are unable to get the exact RAM and CPU utilisation from the hosting provider. I thought about decoupling the database into a seperate instance. But our database is just 70MB and I am not sure if that is worth it. Will also have to get approval from my boss(will most likely turn it down beacuse of the cost ).

Comment: Spot instances are risky right. It will only be allocated if it is available ?

Comment: Yes, they are riskier, but if you design well you  can really gain a lot from them

Comment: I just checked. You won't get a t2 medium in spot instances. Am afraid it will fall outside our budget

Comment: But have a look at an m4 mediu, for example. spot can be up to 90% off